# HDrecover on soft raid arrays

Tags: software-raid

I recently used hdrecover to repair a disk and it successfully repaired three bad sectors.

How does hdrepair function on raid arrays, is it likely to break the array by repairing sectors?

Answer (score 2):

`hdrecover` can damage file systems and RAID systems and it should never be used on a production system - on a RAID other than RAID0 it should be completely unnecessary in the first place as you have a working copy of that broken sector on another disk and the RAID will fix this all by itself when you swap the dead disk.

Citing their [website](http://hdrecover.sourceforge.net/):

> WARNING: A hard disk with bad blocks on is likely to fail! If you
>   value your data you should get a new hard disk instead of using this
>   program!